# async queue hangs when used with background thread

Tags: python, multithreading, async-await, python-multithreading, python-asyncio

It seems `asyncio.Queue` only can be pushed by the same thread reading it? For instance:

```
import asyncio
from threading import Thread
import time

q = asyncio.Queue()

def produce():
    for i in range(100):
        q.put_nowait(i)
        time.sleep(0.1)

async def consume():
    while True:
        i = await q.get()
        print('consumed', i)

Thread(target=produce).start()
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(consume())
```

only prints

```
consumed 0
```

and then hangs. What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't [call asyncio methods from another thread](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-dev.html#concurrency-and-multithreading) directly.

Either use [loop.call_soon_threadsafe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.AbstractEventLoop.call_soon_threadsafe):

```
loop.call_soon_threadsafe(q.put_nowait, i)
```

Or [asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe):

```
future = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(q.put(i), loop)
```

where `loop` is the loop returned by `asyncio.get_event_loop()` *in your main thread*.

Comment: Not having any success with your suggestions (hangs the same way as before), could you please expand into a tiny example?

Comment: Ah. Need to use the same loop as the main thread, and `get_event_loop` is not for that.